# Count from KDB table with where clause

Tags: kdb

I know count table tells you how many rows are in table but how do you count from a table with a where clause as a filter? I tried count table where PERIOD=x but I am getting the error: 'PERIOD even though PERIOD is a field in the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use qsql to filter and then count the result:

```
  count select from table where PERIOD=x
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the count, do

```
exec sum PERIOD=x from table
```

If the table has many columns, this can be much faster than

```
count select from table where PERIOD=x
```

Please note that this computes a sum of booleans as a 32bit int, so if your table has more than a billion rows, you may want to add a cast:

```
exec sum "j"$PERIOD=x from table
```

Answer (score -1):

The following will be the most efficient.

```
select count i from table where PERIOD=x
```

@jomahony solution will require all columns to be read from disk (if the table is on disk) before doing the count so can be inefficient